# ImageMagick identify not working

Tags: debian, imagemagick

I am using Debian Buster and trying to use ImageMagick. I have installed ImageMagick on my system by compiling source files as given in [this](https://imagemagick.org/script/install-source.php) official page. `identify -v` gives me following,

```
Version: ImageMagick 7.0.8-53 Q16 x86_64 2019-07-15 https://imagemagick.org 
Copyright: © 1999-2019 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: https://imagemagick.org/script/license.php Features: Cipher DPC HDRI OpenMP(4.5)  
Delegates (built-in):
```

However when I am trying to see metadata of one of the raw file, it is giving me following error

```
>> identify -verbose _MG_7227.CR2 
identify: unable to open image '/tmp/magick-21769M0_HHYUYw2MT.ppm': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/3497.
```

When I used it on some JPG image, I got some different error message

```
>> identify -verbose IMG_20181226_134152.jpg 
identify: no decode delegate for this image format `JPG' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/556.
```

Can anyone tell me what is going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The

```
Delegates (built-in):
```

line in your `identify --version` output suggests that something went wrong during compilation; I’d expect output more in line with that produced by the packaged version of ImageMagick in Debian:

```
Delegates (built-in): bzlib djvu fftw fontconfig freetype heic jbig jng jp2 jpeg lcms lqr ltdl lzma openexr pangocairo png tiff webp wmf x xml zlib
```

If you don’t mind having a slightly older version of ImageMagick, 6.9.10 rather than 7.0.8, it’s probably simpler for you to use the Debian packages instead:

```
sudo apt install imagemagick
```